# Android View Thumbnail with small video icon on it

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-videoview

Hey guys I want to show a list of feeds in my app.I need to show video thumbnail like facebook.Thumbnail and a small video icon on the center of the image.Kindly help me how can I do that?

I'm using this code to get thumbnail

Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I need to show video thumbnail like facebook.Thumbnail and a small video icon on the center of the image"

For this, you can use a frame layout. Children in a frame layout are drawn on top of another . So, in your case :-

```
<FrameLayout 
    layout_width="match_parent"
    gravity="center"
    layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This for video thumbnail-->
    <Imageview 
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- This for video icon in center-->
    <Imageview 
        layout_width="50dp"
        layout_height="50dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have not written the other properties such as id attribute.
I hope this is what you needed